# Reopen Question: B'Elanna Torres's Head Ridges

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen

I really don't know why this question was closed as being "primarily opinion-based"

[Why didn't B'Elanna Torres have her cranial ridges removed?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/192382/why-didnt-belanna-torres-have-her-cranial-ridges-removed)

This seems (to me) to be a decent question and answerable given the right source material.  I'm a bit lost as to what it was about this question that made it unanswerable.

Can we please reopen this question so that Valorum/any one else can add the promised answer?

Comment: I closed it because I read it as opinion based for why the character didn't want her appearance changed. On re-reading I can see how it can be interpreted to not be opinion based but I'll refrain from posting the final RO vote until a few more opinions have been thrown around just to avoid a close/RO war.

Answer (score 6):

I'm really at a loss why the close voters (Cherubel, TheLethalCarrot, Edlothiad
Loki and T.J.L.) felt that the question was worthy of closure. TLC has [spoken about it in comments](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12017/reopen-question-belanna-torress-head-ridges#comment41098_12017) and seems to have relented in his opinion

> ...On re-reading I can see how it can be interpreted to not be opinion based...

---

This seems to be a perfectly answerable question within the normal scope of the site, not least because we have a wealth of in-universe information (mentioned by Torres herself on at least 5 occasions throughout the run of the show) about how she feels about her Klingon hybrid anatomy.

### The question is now open again and should remain so.

Comment: “Why didn’t `this character` do this?” Reads quite strangely to me, as either a psychology question (off-topic) or opinionated. If they would’ve asked whether it was possible for a doctor to carry out the procedure in such a case (I.e., purely aesthetic) I wouldn’t have felt it was opinion based.

Comment: @Edlothiad - in such a target-rich environment as Trek (complete with shows, movies, novels, etc etc) even *normally opinion-based* questions about motivation become answerable.

Comment: @Edlothiad: Character motivation questions are decidedly on-topic here.

Comment: @Kevin I’ve certainly seen arguments on meta about the points I’d made. I couldn’t recall a specific meta about them, but know the tag exists. That doesn’t mean phrasing isn’t important. They can still be phrased as a psychological question; which would be a science question and off-topic.

Comment: @Edlothiad: It's Klingon psychology, not human psychology, so no, this isn't a science question.  Regardless, if you're willing to stretch the "science question" doctrine that far, you end up declaring half the site off-topic.

Comment: @Edlothiad Usually, perhaps. But in this case it was explicitly mentioned in the series. Pretty much an entire episode was devoted to the issue when she was pregnant.

Comment: @Edlothiad We have a character motivation tag. I always include it in my "Why did/didn't X do this?" questions. According to your view, character motivation questions should all be closed.

Comment: @C.Koca that’s correct. If they’re asking us about to assess the psychology of a character, they should be closed, that’s a science question.

Comment: @Edlothiad No. Their motivation may depend on scifi elements. Even if they are not, their psychology is an inherent part of the works. For example, we answer many game of thrones or lord of the rings question by making conjectures with medieval world. Why can't we do similar conjectures for psychology questions? Besides, there are 220 tagged questions in character motivation and 70 in character development. Good luck VTCing all of them.

Comment: @C.Koca Not saying I agree or disagree here but lots of questions that should be closed should never be a reason for why they should be allowed.